# Updating multiple Eloquent models with different values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a `Parent` model with a `hasMany` relationship to a `Child` model. I would like to update a single property in each child with a specific and different value. How can I do this?

I know I can use mass assignment to update the property in each child with the same value, i.e.

```php
Parent::findOrFail($id)->children()->update(["property"=>"new value"])
```

But how do I do this with individually set values?
e.g. if my Parent has 4 children I would like to set it with something like this

```php
Parent::findOrFail($id)->children()->update(["property"=>[1,2,3,4]])
```

And then child one would have 1, child two has 2 etc.

Comment: `update` method update the exiating data. In your case you have new value? Then you need to create, or use `updateOrCreate` method. But unfortunately there are no any `updateOrCreateMany` method on 5.7. On 8.x you can use **[upserts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)** method to update bulk query

Comment: Loop over `children()` and update one-by-one, or append to an update SQL statement. You can use the loop index if you want; `foreach(...->children() as $index => child){ $child->update(['property' => $index]); }`, etc etc.

Comment: There are loads of ways of doing this; a loop over the `children` collection being the easiest. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, looping over the relationship collection:

```php
$values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$parent
    ->children
    ->each(fn ($child, $k) => $child->update(["property" => $values[$k] ?? null]));
```

Or, if you're using an unsupported old version of PHP:

```php
$values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$parent->children->each(function ($child, $k) use ($values) {
    $child->update(["property" => $values[$k] ?? null]);
});
```